# 60's-70's sci-fi book, sentient robots go to capture their ageing "father" to robotify him and preserve him

Tags: story-identification, books, robots, androids

A while back, I was working in a max security hospital. I came across a book, and started reading it during down time. It was a collection of short stories themed with robots/androids. It was an older book, 60's-70's. It wasn't Asimov. Possibly though I don't think it was, Gibson.

I only made it through a couple of chapters of the first story before it disappeared the next day. I can't remember the title, nor the author.

The story was about the "father" of the robots - the engineer responsible for first creating them. Years later, his work lead to a revolution/evolution of sentient robots/androids. Upon hearing that he was slowly dying of old age, the robots set out to capture him with intentions to "robotify" him in order to preserve his life - as they didn't want their father to die; the clincher was they'd have to essentially kill him in order to do it.

I only made it to the part where they were explaining what they wanted to do.

Comment: Not quite what you're describing, but possibly With Folded Hands?

Answer (score 12):

Sounds like Rudy Rucker's "[Software](https://www.bookdepository.com/Software-Rudy-Rucker/9781511319911)", first of the "'Ware" tetralogy, published in 1982.

> It was Cobb Anderson who built the"boppers"--the first robots with real brains. Now, in 2020, Cobb is just another aged "pheezer" with a bad heart, drinking and grooving an the old tunes in Florida retirement hell. His "bops" have came a long way, though, rebelling against their subjugation to set up their own society an the moon. And now they're offering creator Cobb immortality but at a stiff price: his body his soul ... and his world.

Available [free on the author's website](http://www.rudyrucker.com/wares/).

Comment: Yes!!! That's it! Thank you!

Comment: Nicely found, +1! I looked hard for this one, came up dry.

Comment: @Rob if this is the answer, you might want to hit the check mark to set it as the best answer so the question is resolved.